# PyQt: How to stick QHBoxLayout to dialog's bottom edge

Tags: python, pyqt

ekhumoro beautifully solved this issue for **QFormLayout** by using:

```
myQFormLayout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtGui.QFormLayout.AllNonFixedFieldsGrow)
```

What would be a correct syntax to achieve the same with **QHBoxLayout**?

Screenshot below shows GroupBoxAs' and GroupBoxB are not sticking to the dialog windows...

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, os

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        myBoxLayout.setFieldGrowthPolicy(QtGui.QFormLayout.AllNonFixedFieldsGrow)
        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)    

        GroupBoxA = QtGui.QGroupBox('GroupBoxA') 
        LayoutA = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() 
        GroupBoxA.setLayout(LayoutA)

        GroupBoxB = QtGui.QGroupBox('GroupBoxB') 
        LayoutB = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() 
        GroupBoxB.setLayout(LayoutB)    

        myBoxLayout.addRow(GroupBoxA, GroupBoxB)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching I ended up of using QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout. These layouts resize properly (on windows and mac). A combinations of twos could be used to achieve some  interesting widgets placement. Here is the one I put together:
[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, os

class Dialog_01(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QtGui.QMainWindow,self).__init__()

        myQWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        myBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        myQWidget.setLayout(myBoxLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(myQWidget)    

        # Top GroupBox
        TopGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('TopGroupBox')
        TopLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        TopGroupBox.setLayout(TopLayout)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(TopGroupBox)

        # Middle GroupBox
        MiddleGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('MiddleGroupBox')
        MiddleLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        MiddleGroupBox.setLayout(MiddleLayout)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(MiddleGroupBox)

        # Bottom GroupBox
        BottomGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('BottomGroupBox')
        BottomLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        BottomGroupBox.setLayout(BottomLayout)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(BottomGroupBox)

        # Left Bottom Horizontal GroupBox
        LeftHorGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Left Horizontal')
        LeftHorLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        LeftHorGroupBox.setLayout(LeftHorLayout)

        # Left Bottom Horizontal GroupBox
        RightVertGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('Right Vertical')
        RightVertLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        RightVertGroupBox.setLayout(RightVertLayout)

        BottomLayout.addWidget(LeftHorGroupBox)
        BottomLayout.addWidget(RightVertGroupBox)

        viewA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        viewB=QtGui.QListWidget()
        viewC=QtGui.QListWidget()
        LeftHorLayout.addWidget(viewA)
        LeftHorLayout.addWidget(viewB)
        LeftHorLayout.addWidget(viewC)

        widgetA=QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        widgetB=QtGui.QLineEdit('Some cool LineEdit')
        widgetC=QtGui.QLabel('Some cool Label')
        widgetD=QtGui.QComboBox()
        widgetE=QtGui.QCheckBox('Some cool QCheckBox')
        widgetF = QtGui.QDateEdit()
        RightVertLayout.addWidget(widgetA)
        RightVertLayout.addWidget(widgetB)
        RightVertLayout.addWidget(widgetC)
        RightVertLayout.addWidget(widgetD)
        RightVertLayout.addWidget(widgetE)
        RightVertLayout.addWidget(widgetF)


        # Buttons GroupBox
        ButtonsGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox('ButtonsGroupBox')
        ButtonsLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        ButtonsGroupBox.setLayout(ButtonsLayout)
        myBoxLayout.addWidget(ButtonsGroupBox)
        Button_01 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button_01")
        Button_02 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button_02")
        ButtonsLayout.addWidget(Button_01)
        ButtonsLayout.addWidget(Button_02)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog_1 = Dialog_01()
    dialog_1.show()
    dialog_1.resize(480,320)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```